# value of hook not update

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following:

```
const [quantityKm, setQuantityX] = useState({ x: 0 });
```

I have a range that when it changes the following function is executed

```
const handleKmValue = (event) => {
    const { x } = event;
    setQuantityX({ x: x});
};
```

And then, if I change a `<select>` this function must be executed

```
const calculatePrice = () => {
    console.log(quantityKm.x);
    setValueMonth((parseFloat(quantityKm.x.toFixed(2)) * valueOfKm))
};
```

However, I always receive the value of `quantityKm.x` as 0

Comment: What event is this being called on?

Comment: The order is as I wrote it, the `select` calls `onChange=handleKmValue `, saves the value of `valueMonth` and calls fn `calculatePrice` which is where `valueMonth` and `quantityKm` have values ​​of 0.

Comment: @Mickey yes, if I print `event.x` it is perfect, but if I print `quantityKm.x` after `setQuantityX` the value is 0

Comment: Since setState is async, it's likely that `calculatePrice` fires before `quantityKm` can update if you're calling `calculatePrice` in the same function where you call `handleKmValue`. You should move `calculatePrice` into its own [`useEffect()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook.

Comment: I thought so, but I didn't find a way to call a function or execute code after the `setState` is finished running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, it sounds like your code is structured as follows:

```
const [quantityKm, setQuantityX] = useState({ x: 0 });

const handleKmValue = ...
const calculatePrice = ...

const handleChange = event => {
    handleKmValue(event);
    calculatePrice();
}

<Select onChange={handleChange} />
```

Instead, use:

```
const [quantityKm, setQuantityX] = useState({ x: 0 });

useEffect(() => {
    // move the calculatePrice functionality into the effect
    console.log(quantityKm.x);
    setValueMonth((parseFloat(quantityKm.x.toFixed(2)) * valueOfKm))

}, [quantityKm.x]) // run effect if value's changed

<Select onChange={handleKmValue} />
```